# How to get an image from FirebaseStorage using future?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this function that gets the url of the image I want to show

```
_getImage(photoUrl) async {
    final ref = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(photoUrl);
    String url =  await ref.getDownloadURL();
    return url;
  }
```

then I want to use it in a Builder:

```
body: !isLoading
            ? ListView.builder(
            itemCount: items.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, i) {
             DetailListItem item = items[i];

              String imageUrl;
              _getImage(item.imageName).then((data) {
                setState(() {
                  imageUrl = data;
                  print('data herereeerererer $imageUrl');
                });
              });

child: Card(
                            color: CustomColors.newCreme,
                            margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 7,
                                top: 0,
                                bottom: 7),
                            elevation: 7,
                            child: Center(
                              child: imageUrl == null ? Column(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.arrowLeft,
                                    color: CustomColors.newOrange,
                                    size: SizeConfig.blockSizeHorizontal * 10,),
                                  SizedBox(
                                    height: SizeConfig.blockSizeHorizontal *
                                        1.7,),
                                  Text('Sin Foto', style: TextStyle(
                                    color: CustomColors.newViolet,
                                    fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                                    fontSize: SizeConfig.blockSizeHorizontal *
                                        5.0,
                                  )
                                  )
                                ],
                              ) : Image.network(imageUrl),
```

But it seems I'm missing something because it only shows the Text "Sin Foto" despite the imageUrl is updated.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: maybe one of your items doesn't have imageUrl, then it will update `imageUrl` to null and you won't see the image

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you are updating your `State`, which will rebuild all of your `body` and not just the item in the `ListView`. There would be ways to salvage that using your `setState` attempt by extracting the widget or using a [`StatefulBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulBuilder-class.html), but the idiomatic way is using a [`FutureBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) for this task instead as it handles the state management for you.

So this is how you can use `FutureBuilder`:

```dart
(context, i) {
  DetailListItem item = items[i];

  return Card(
      color: CustomColors.newCreme,
      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 7, top: 0, bottom: 7),
      elevation: 7,
      child: FutureBuilder(
        future: _getImage(item.imageName),
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData)
            return Center(
              child: Image.network(snapshot.data),
            );

          // Return your "Sin Foto" text here.
          return Column(...);
        },
      ));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it doesn't work for me. When I load the list, the first 2 items appears with images, the rest doesn't but it should, then when I scroll the list, the first image disappear, then if I return to the home screen and load the list there are no images at all. Now I'm thinking to submit to Firebase the downloadable link (not sure if it's good idea) and then use it with Image.network. Thank you anyway!

Comment: Ok, it seems the rest of the images, appears too, but it's too slow and the problem with the scroll persists, thought it has to do with the Keys.

Comment: Not sure what you mean.

Comment: well I'm not sure too :) I watched a video by the flutter team about a hacker news app, and I remember that, there were some problems with the list tiles they used to show the data, because of the key thing https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Widget/key.html